# Graphviz DOT edge arrowhead and arrowtail inverted (randomly) if splines=ortho is set

Tags: graph-theory, graphviz, dot

If setting **splines=ortho** and the **edge direction** to **both** and defining an **arrowhead and an arrowtail different from "none"** (see reproduction steps), the two ends get mixed up. So the head and the tail part of the edge is randomly inverted.

**Reproduction steps** on Windows 7 (64-bit) and using Graphviz-2.38.

*Case 1 (without splines=ortho) - edge ends as expected*

```
digraph Test {
    edge [dir = both, arrowhead = dot, arrowtail = curve, headlabel="Head", taillabel="Tail"];  
    A -> B;
    A -> C;
    D -> C; 
}
```

*Case 2 (with splines=ortho set) - edge ends between A->B and D->C inverted*

```
digraph Test {
    splines = ortho;
    edge [dir = both, arrowhead = dot, arrowtail = curve, headlabel="Head", taillabel="Tail"];  
    A -> B;
    A -> C;
    D -> C;
}
```

See generated graphs at:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOfHM.png]

I don't know if this is a DOT bug concerning the splines=ortho setting or I just miss something.

Furthermore, if adding for example E -> C edge it will be displayed correctly (only A->B and D->C is wrong). If adding another F -> C edge, all edges with target node C are correct, but not A->B.

It somehow relates to the number of edges that have the target node C.

Comment: I have the same problem with Graphivz-2.40.1 on Mac. I really think it's a bug and confirm it appears only with splines=ortho. From my experiments trying to figure out a rule to work around it I think it as more to do with the ranking of the nodes by the layout engine.

Comment: Hi Friends, has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: [A link to the issue and the developer's response.](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/144#note_326549080) Citate: `we don’t have anyone able to maintain this code now`.

Comment: I think it got fixed by now.